# laravel 4 handle not found in Route::model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

when use "Route::model" in routes.php

```
Route::model('pizza', 'Pizza');

Route::get('edit/{pizza}', 'PizzaController@edit');
```

I receive error if "id" not found in DB, how to display custom message in this status?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel will throw a 404 error if the model binding fails. So what you'll want to do is provide a closure as a third parameter to override the behavior and throw a different error:

```
Route::model('pizza', 'Pizza', function()
{
    throw new ModelNotFoundException; // or NotFoundHttpException or PizzaNotFoundException...
});
```

See: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding

Once you have that in place, you can catch the exception and handle it however you'd like in `app/start/global.php`

See: http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors

Or instead of throwing an exception, you could just use the closure to return a `Redirect` response to a specific page with a flash message indicating the error.