# Laravel 4 route-model binding exceptions doesn't work despite docs and examples

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I read a lot about Laravel4 Route-model binding (L4 docs, tutorials, etc.) but still exceptions (i.e. the model is not found) don't work for me

These are my basic files

routes.php:

```
Route::model('game', 'Game', function(){
    // override default 404 behavior if model not found, see Laravel docs        
    return Redirect::to('/games');
});
...
Route::get('/games/edit/{game}', 'GamesController@edit');
```

GamesController.php

```
class GamesController extends BaseController {
    ...
    public function edit(Game $game){
        return View::make('/games/edit', compact('game'));
    }
}
```

Pretty straight, but I get this error: `Argument 1 passed to GamesController::edit() must be an instance of Game, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given`

If I type http://mysite.dev/games/edit/1 all is fine (model with ID = 1 exists)

If I type http://mysite.dev/games/edit/12345 (no model with that ID) the ugly error above is triggered instead of the redirect I specified

I also looked at this (the bottom part where a Redirect closure is suggested: that is just what I am doing!) but no way to make it work: [laravel 4 handle not found in Route::model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588480/laravel-4-handle-not-found-in-routemodel)

What's wrong with it? Please any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Route::model you declare which variable will be a model instance, you shouldn't use it to do a redirection that way. Instead of that, specify that `$game` is of type `Game` and then work with your routes:

```
Route::model('game', 'Game');
...
Route::get('/games/edit/{game}', 'GamesController@edit');
```

Then if you access to `/games/edit/3` GamesController::edit will receive an instance of `Game` class whose `id=3`

Comment: Your example is fine, until a bad user types something like http://mysite.dev/games/edit/123456 (non existing ID) that triggers an error. Laravel documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding) states "If you wish to specify your own "not found" behavior, you may pass a Closure as the third argument to the model method" that is what I am just trying to do with a Redirect: it doesn't prevent me to do that, in theory...

Comment: Route::get('/games', 'GamesController@index');

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by setting a general "Not Found" error catcher, like this:

```
// routes.php
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e) {
    return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
});
...
Route::model('game', 'Game');
...
Route::get('/games/edit/{game}', 'GamesController@edit');
```

What I understand is that if I want a *custom* redirect and not a general 404 page (i.e. take the user to games' list if model not found), I CAN'T use the route-model-binding

In other words, I have to use `Route::get('/games/edit/{id}', 'GamesController@edit');` and then do my application logic inside the 'edit' method:

```
public function edit($id){
    $game = Game::findOrFail($id);
    // if fails then redirect to custom page, else go on saving
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Laravel, but as far as I can see this has nothing to do with the closure, but with the use of "Redirect::to" inside that closure. Using "App::abort( 404 );" works.